# Generating the "drawing commands" from ASSdraw3 using other vector programs

Tags: vector, overlay

```
m -36 -35 b -31 -23 -32 -13 -17 -11 b -15 -1 1 -6 -4 -15 b 9 -11 7 -7 4 4 b 11 -12 12 -9 21 1 b 24 -9 11 -20 28 -22 b 28 -17 32 -15 44 -17 b 35 -7 35 -1 40 5 b 29 8 24 12 19 24 b 9 16 1 18 -8 19 b -8 19 -8 19 -10 27 b -15 18 -21 17 -46 25 b -32 13 -36 9 -56 18 b -42 1 -45 -3 -60 -2 b -47 -12 -48 -16 -54 -20 b -47 -23 -47 -26 -43 -30 b -39 -25 -31 -21 -28 -3 b -24 -21 -23 -26 -4 -41 b -10 -29 7 -27 10 -39 b 16 -28 26 -23 15 -16
```

The program assdraw, allows you to create vector graphics for the purpose of adding them to aegisub to include as pseudo 'image overlays' in the creation of your subfile. 
The program is fairly limiting though.

I was wondering if there were other programs that can generate the strings of information like the above, or that could be converted to do so. Reading the manual there doesn't seem to be a way to import outside images to use as anything other than tracing references.

I couldn't find information on whether the relationship between aegisub and assdraw was open or one way. In other words is assdraw the only program allowed to generate vector overlays for aegisub, for use in aegisub's {\p1}{\p0} tags?

I feel like I"m missing something here as I have only been able to output singular colour simple objects from assdraw...which become treated like text when they get into aegisub so you have limited options on adding shadows/borders/fades/transforms and 4 things that can be coloured etc.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software you mention. Can you check if it can import SVGs?  If so, there's lots of vector software that can create SVGs. Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape (which is free), CorelDraw etc.